# .blend object appears black on Web4Web Fast Preview

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, blend-files, units, blend4web, blend-modes

So i got this .blend object from a website and i transported it into my blender file that I'm working. Everything works fine except when i go to blend4web and i pressed "Fast Preview", the object turns completely black even though i added some color 
[image][image]

I'm really new to blender. I tried everything but i have no idea what the problem. I feel stupid because it probably something simple. Thanks ahead for all the help guys

Answer (score 1):

You need a source of light. You can add a simple point light : Shift+A / Lamp / Point